# Chart.js keep two charts side by side on one canvas

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

Like in the title I would like to use one canvas to share by chart.js. I have seen [side by side with DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30901058/chartjs-keeping-2-graphs-aligned-side-by-side), but this is something else, I need to keep one canvas and preserve animations.

I use Chart.js version: 2.8.0 (latest), wth idea to relayout plot via registering plugin. First part works like charm, in `beforeLayout`

```
chart.width = chart.canvas.width * 0.6;
```

this scales first plot, works perfectly, even tooltips are displayed only within first plots area. With second plot if I set:

```
chart.width = chart.canvas.width * 0.4;
chart.options.layout.padding.left = chart.canvas.width * 0.6;
```

Plot gets confused, stacks[image: confused plot chart.js]

clearly I can set

```
 chart.width = chart.canvas.width * 1;
```

and redraw first plot afterwards, but maybe there is some simple way to keep two (or more) plots sharing canvas?

Code taken from [chart.js samples](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/bar/vertical.html) and modified by me to produce minimal working example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <title>Line Chart</title>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="1013" height="506" class="chartjs-render-monitor"></canvas>
 <br>
 <button id="randomizeData">Randomize Data</button>
 <script>
  var config = {
   type: 'bar',
   data: {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
    datasets: [{
     label: 'My First dataset',
     backgroundColor: 'green',
     borderColor: 'blue',
     data: [
      Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()
     ],
     fill: false,
    }, {
     label: 'My Second dataset',
     fill: false,
     backgroundColor: 'blue',
     borderColor: 'blue',
     data: [
      Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()
     ],
    }]
   },
   plugins: [{
    beforeLayout: function (chart) {
     chart.width = chart.canvas.width * 0.6;
     chart.options.layout.padding.left = 0;
    },

   }],
   options: {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
     display: true,
     text: 'Chart.js Line Chart'
    },
    tooltips: {
     mode: 'index',
     intersect: false,
    },
    hover: {
     mode: 'nearest',
     intersect: true
    },
    scales: {
     xAxes: [{
      display: true,
      scaleLabel: {
       display: true,
       labelString: 'Month'
      }
     }],
     yAxes: [{
      display: true,
      scaleLabel: {
       display: true,
       labelString: 'Value'
      }
     }]
    }
   }
  };

  var config2 = {
   type: 'bar',
   data: {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
    datasets: [{
     label: 'My First dataset',
     backgroundColor: 'green',
     borderColor: 'blue',
     data: [
      Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()
     ],
     fill: false,
    }, {
     label: 'My Second dataset',
     fill: false,
     backgroundColor: 'blue',
     borderColor: 'blue',
     data: [
      Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()
     ],
    }]
   },
   plugins: [{
    beforeLayout: function (chart) {
     chart.width = chart.canvas.width * 0.4;
     chart.options.layout.padding.left = chart.canvas.width * 0.6;
    },

   }],
   options: {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
     display: true,
     text: 'Chart.js Line Chart'
    },
    tooltips: {
     mode: 'index',
     intersect: false,
    },
    hover: {
     mode: 'nearest',
     intersect: true
    },
    scales: {
     xAxes: [{
      display: true,
      scaleLabel: {
       display: true,
       labelString: 'Month'
      }
     }],
     yAxes: [{
      display: true,
      scaleLabel: {
       display: true,
       labelString: 'Value'
      }
     }]
    }
   }
  };

  window.onload = function() {
   var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
   window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, config);
   window.myLine2 = new Chart(ctx, config2);
  };

  document.getElementById('randomizeData').addEventListener('click', function() {
   config.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
    dataset.data = dataset.data.map(function() {
     return Math.random();
    });
   });

   config2.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
    dataset.data = dataset.data.map(function() {
     return Math.random();
    });
   });

   window.myLine.update();
   window.myLine2.update();
  });

 </script>
</body></html>
```

This is how desired result looks like:
[image: desired result]
Things like missing Y axis, legend and title are hidden with
 simple `display: false`, and second's plot padding top is set to first's plot chartArea.top, problem here is flickering and too often redraw of first plot, it also receives hover events, so setting padding alone is no go, so there should be offset for second plot set somehow.

Now, I took effort in meanwhile to modify a bit and decide to clear on my own, the buggy thing left is tooltip, fired in both plots and vertical shift between bars of both plots. It also requires manual redraw on resize.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <title>Line Chart</title>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div>
<canvas id="canvas" width="1013" height="506" class="chartjs-render-monitor"></canvas>
</div>
 <br>
 <button id="randomizeData">Randomize Data</button>
 <script>
  var config = {
   type: 'horizontalBar',
   data: {
    labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul'],
    datasets: [{
     label: 'My First dataset',
     backgroundColor: 'green',
     borderColor: 'blue',
     data: [
      Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()
     ]
    }, {
     backgroundColor: 'blue',
     borderColor: 'blue',
     data: [
      Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()
     ],
    }]
   },
   plugins: [{
    beforeLayout: function (chart) {
     chart.width = chart.canvas.width * 0.55;
     chart.options.layout.padding.left = 0;
    },

   }],
   onResize: function() {
   console.log(3)
   },
   options: {
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
     display: false
    },
    title: {
     display: true,
     text: 'Chart.js Test double plot'
    },
    tooltips: {
     mode: 'index',
     intersect: false,
    },
    hover: {
     mode: 'label',
     intersect: true
    },
    scales: {
     xAxes: [{
      display: false,
      scaleLabel: {
       display: true,
       labelString: 'Month'
      }
     }],
     yAxes: [{
      display: true,
               gridLines: {
       display:false
      }
     }]
    }
   }
  };

  var config2 = {
   type: 'horizontalBar',
   data: {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
    datasets: [{
     backgroundColor: 'green',
     borderColor: 'blue',
     data: [
      Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()
     ],
     fill: false,
    }, {
     backgroundColor: 'blue',
     borderColor: 'blue',
     data: [
      Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()
     ],
    }]
   },
   plugins: [{
    beforeLayout: function (chart) {
     chart.options.layout.padding.left = chart.canvas.width * 0.55;
     chart.options.layout.padding.top = myLine.chartArea.top;
    },

    afterDraw: function (chart) {
     myLine.update();
    },

   }],
   options: {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
     display: false,
    },
    legend: {
     display: false
    },
    tooltips: {
     mode: 'index',
     intersect: false,
    },
    hover: {
     mode: 'label',
     intersect: true
    },
    scales: {
     xAxes: [{
      gridLines: {
       display:false
      },   
      display: false,
      scaleLabel: {
       display: true,
      }
     }],
     yAxes: [{
      display: false,
     }]
    }
   }
  };

  window.onload = function() {
   var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
   window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, config);
   myLine.clear = function() {
    var canvas = this.ctx;
    canvas.clearRect(0, 0, this.chartArea.right, this.height); return this.canvas;}
   window.myLine2 = new Chart(ctx, config2);
   myLine2.clear = function() {
   var canvas = this.ctx;
   canvas.clearRect(this.chartArea.left, 0, this.chartArea.right - this.chartArea.left + 15, this.height); return this.canvas;}
  };

  document.getElementById('randomizeData').addEventListener('click', function() {
   config.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
    dataset.data = dataset.data.map(function() {
     return Math.random();
    });
   });

   config2.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
    dataset.data = dataset.data.map(function() {
     return Math.random();
    });
   });

   window.myLine.update();
   window.myLine2.update();
  });

 </script>
</body></html>
```

It would even stick with many updates firing, but tooltips got cut out, there are two present at the same time, during animation. This result looks almost like final version, so in case someone wonders why, these are four variables for same data, two coupled ones. Since there are only bars and tooltips left, I would draw a few rectangles myself if not for animation and same framework used for other plots. Pipeline for further processing requies one image, so hacking on demand canvas to draw both of them is no way to go.

The problem underneath is that padding or margin gets ignored by Chart.js when redraw occurs.

[image: two charts, buggy]

Comment: To downvoter / closer: case is simple to put two charts at one canvas, it is narrow in my opinion. I have provided semi-working code, which needs an idea or a few lines of hacks. In meanwhile I have seen Chart.js issues and there is no support for multiple charts at one canvas, but it seems that people are interested in solution. If there are other issues I will gladly adress them. Thank you.

Comment: Refer to this example code: https://jsfiddle.net/r0qnob1t/