# Is it possible to align vertical stacked plots

Tags: chart.js

I'm struggling to align vertically stacked line graphs so that the x-axis visually align. Does anyone have suggestions about how to do this?

Example stacked plots

[image]

Comment: There is no built-in method for that AFAIK. Some people have achieved that through this workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30901058/chartjs-keeping-2-graphs-aligned-side-by-side. However I would say that playing with `options.layout.padding.left` is the easiest way to fix it by adding a [padding](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/layout.html).