# Chart.js v3 keeping 2 graphs aligned side by side

Tags: chart.js

How can I align two graphs side by side, similar to what is described in this Stack Overflow post [Chartjs - keeping 2 graphs aligned side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30901058/chartjs-keeping-2-graphs-aligned-side-by-side), using Chart.js v3?
Here is my code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.4.1/chart.js"></script>
    <style>
        #chart_a, #chart_b {
            width: 320px;
            height: 350px;
        }
        .label {
            text-align: center;
            width: 600px;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: bold;
            margin: 20px;
        }
        .chart_container {
            float: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="aligned">
        <div class="label">Aligned</div>
        <div class="chart_container">
            <canvas id="chart_a"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="chart_container">
            <canvas id="chart_b"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
var data, ctx;
data = {
    labels: ["Dmitri.Ivanovich.Mendeleev", "Yuri.Alekseyevich.Gagarin", "Alexey.Arkhipovich.Leonov"],
    datasets: [{
        label: "My First dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
        highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
        highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: [50, 88, 15]
    }]
};

console.log(document.getElementById("chart_b"))
ctx = document.getElementById("chart_b").getContext("2d");

var mychart2 = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: {
        animation: false
    }
});

/*
// This code is valid only for v1
Chart.types.Bar.extend({
    name: "BarAlt",
    draw: function () {
        this.scale.endPoint = this.options.endPoint;
        Chart.types.Bar.prototype.draw.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});
*/
data = {
    labels: ["Iantojones", "Jackharkness", "Owenharper"],
    datasets: [{
        label: "My First dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
        highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
        highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: [50, 88, 15]
    }]
};

ctx = document.getElementById("chart_a").getContext("2d");
var mychart1 = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',  // type: 'barAlt'
  data: data, 
  options: {
    animation: false,
    // endPoint: mychart2.scale.endPoint,
  },
});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

While I realized that achieving the same functionality as in v2 using `chart.helpers.extend` is possible, I’m unsure of the alternative approach in v3 since the helpers have been removed.
It seems good to use this in the ES2015 class as shown in https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.4.1/developers/charts.html, but I don't know how to import BarController.

Unexpected Result:
[image]

Expected Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Update note:** Although this solution was implemented for chart.js version 3.4.1. as it was asked, it works without change with the current version, 4.4.1.

Aside from several technical complications (like the layout of chart.js is now
quite sophisticated, one cannot change the height of the y-axis by just setting
a variable), there is the issue with label rotation: the default way label
rotation is computed allows large labels to extend to the left of the chart area
compressing it to the right, (which is described as not desired in the question).
I solve this problem through a plugin that employs some trigonometry
to compute a new rotation of the labels such that the chart area may have its
full possible width. That plugin uses the [`afterLayout`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#chart-update)
hook, as it's the earliest stage where the sizes of the axes are computed.

Setting `maintainAspectRatio: false` is a must even if the canvas is not resized
dynamically, since it allows the chart area to extend to the maximum available
space, regardless of the size of the canvas.

The main part of the problem, also implemented in the `afterLayout` hook
is simple: [`resize`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#resize-width-height)
the first chart such that the `bottom` value of the `chartArea` is the same with
the `bottom` of the `chartArea` for the second chart.

```js
const data1 = {
    labels: ["Iantojones", "Jackharkness", "Owenharper"],
    datasets: [{
        label: "My First dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
        highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
        highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: [50, 88, 15]
    }]
};

const data2 = {
    labels: ["Dmitri.Ivanovich.Mendeleev", "Yuri.Alekseyevich.Gagarin", "Alexey.Arkhipovich.Leonov"],
    datasets: [{
        label: "My First dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
        highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
        highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: [50, 88, 15]
    }]
};

const mychart2 = new Chart("chart_b", {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data2,
    options: {
        animation: false,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        layout:{
            autoPadding: false,
            //padding: {left: 20, bottom: 30} // test with padding
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        {
            afterLayout(chart){
                //label rotation
                if(!chart.__rotationFixed){ // run only once, avoid infinite recursion
                    chart.__rotationFixed = true;
                    const xScale = chart.scales.x,
                        yScale = chart.scales.y;
                    const extraSpaceToLeft = yScale.left - yScale.paddingLeft;
                    if(extraSpaceToLeft > 5){
                        const currentLeft = chart.chartArea.left,
                            minTheoreticalLeft = yScale.width,
                            currentRotation = xScale.labelRotation * Math.PI / 180,
                            label0XG = xScale.getPixelForValue(xScale.ticks[0].value),
                            label0Length = label0XG / Math.cos(currentRotation),
                            cosMin = (label0XG - currentLeft + minTheoreticalLeft) / label0Length,
                            minRotation = cosMin < 0 ? 90 : Math.acos(cosMin) * 180 / Math.PI;
                        const gainToLeft = label0XG - label0Length * cosMin;
                        if(cosMin > 0 && Math.abs(gainToLeft - extraSpaceToLeft) > 10){
                            console.warn(`Assumption failed; rotation possibly miscalculated! `+
                                `extraSpaceToLeft = ${extraSpaceToLeft} gainToLeft = ${gainToLeft}`)
                        }

                        xScale.options.ticks.minRotation = minRotation;
                        xScale.options.ticks.maxRotation = minRotation;
                        chart.options.scales.x.ticks.minRotation = minRotation;
                        chart.options.scales.x.ticks.maxRotation = minRotation;

                        chart._updateLayout(chart._minPadding); // hacky, but cleaner
                        //chart.update('none');  // documented alternative to the above
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
});

/*const mychart1 = */new Chart("chart_a", {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data1,
    options: {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        animation: false,
    },
    plugins:[
        {
            afterLayout(chart){
                // resize the first chart
                if(!chart.__resized){ // run only once, avoid infinite recursion
                    chart.__resized = true;
                    const deltaY = mychart2.chartArea.bottom - chart.chartArea.bottom;
                    chart.resize(chart.canvas.offsetWidth, chart.canvas.offsetHeight + deltaY);
                }
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

```css
#chart_a, #chart_b{
    width: 320px;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.7); /* to see what's happening */
}
.label {
    text-align: center;
    width: 600px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 20px;
}
#aligned{
    min-width: 650px
}
.chart_container {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="aligned">
    <div class="label">Aligned</div>

    <div class="chart_container" id="container_a">
        <canvas id="chart_a"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="chart_container" id="container_b">
        <canvas id="chart_b"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.4.1/chart.js"></script>
<!--script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.4.1/chart.umd.js"></script-->
```

This solution has the advantage (compared with the linked one for an old version of
chart.js) that there's no empty space in the canvases, so they could go vertically
in a narrow medium.

Also, it can immediately be adapted to resize (enlarge) the second chart such that
it fits the first one.

```js
const data1 = {
    labels: ["Iantojones", "Jackharkness", "Owenharper"],
    datasets: [{
        label: "My First dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
        highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
        highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: [50, 88, 15]
    }]
};

const data2 = {
    labels: ["Dmitri.Ivanovich.Mendeleev", "Yuri.Alekseyevich.Gagarin", "Alexey.Arkhipovich.Leonov"],
    datasets: [{
        label: "My First dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
        highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
        highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: [50, 88, 15]
    }]
};

const mychart1 = new Chart("chart_a", {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data1,
    options: {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        animation: false,
    }
});


/*const mychart2 = */new Chart("chart_b", {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data2,
    options: {
        animation: false,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        layout:{
            autoPadding: false,
            //padding: {left: 20, bottom: 30} // test with padding
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        {
            afterLayout(chart){
                //label rotation
                if(!chart.__rotationFixed){ // run only once, avoid infinite recursion
                    chart.__rotationFixed = true;
                    const xScale = chart.scales.x,
                        yScale = chart.scales.y;
                    const extraSpaceToLeft = yScale.left - yScale.paddingLeft;
                    if(extraSpaceToLeft > 5){
                        const currentLeft = chart.chartArea.left,
                            minTheoreticalLeft = yScale.width,
                            currentRotation = xScale.labelRotation * Math.PI / 180,
                            label0XG = xScale.getPixelForValue(xScale.ticks[0].value),
                            label0Length = label0XG / Math.cos(currentRotation),
                            cosMin = (label0XG - currentLeft + minTheoreticalLeft) / label0Length,
                            minRotation = cosMin < 0 ? 90 : Math.acos(cosMin) * 180 / Math.PI;
                        const gainToLeft = label0XG - label0Length * cosMin;
                        if(cosMin > 0 && Math.abs(gainToLeft - extraSpaceToLeft) > 10){
                            console.warn(`Assumption failed; rotation possibly miscalculated! `+
                                `extraSpaceToLeft = ${extraSpaceToLeft} gainToLeft = ${gainToLeft}`)
                        }

                        xScale.options.ticks.minRotation = minRotation;
                        xScale.options.ticks.maxRotation = minRotation;
                        chart.options.scales.x.ticks.minRotation = minRotation;
                        chart.options.scales.x.ticks.maxRotation = minRotation;

                        chart._updateLayout(chart._minPadding); // hacky, but cleaner
                        //chart.update('none');  // documented alternative to the above
                    }
                }

                // resize the second chart
                if(!chart.__resized && chart.__rotationFixed){ // run only once, avoid infinite recursion
                    chart.__resized = true;
                    const deltaY = mychart1.chartArea.bottom - chart.chartArea.bottom;
                    chart.resize(chart.canvas.offsetWidth, chart.canvas.offsetHeight + deltaY);
                }
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

```css
#chart_a, #chart_b{
    width: 320px;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.7); /* to see what's happening */
}
.label {
    text-align: center;
    width: 600px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 20px;
}
#aligned{
    min-width: 650px
}
.chart_container {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="aligned">
    <div class="label">Aligned</div>

    <div class="chart_container" id="container_a">
        <canvas id="chart_a"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="chart_container" id="container_b">
        <canvas id="chart_b"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.4.1/chart.js"></script>
```